# weird compiler behavior with switch type pattern usage

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

In the following code it does not matter whether I try to access `s` or `o`, in both cases the compiler complains that the variables are not initialized. I would expect that at least `o` always being initialized since it is the most unspecific type. So why the compiler does even allow me to specify variables in that scenario?

```
void Foo(object obj)
{       
        switch (obj)
        {
            case string s:
            case object o:
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                break;
        }      
}
```

I am using .NET 7.

Comment: If it matched `string s`, then `o` is not assigned, and if it matched `object o` (was that a typo?), then `s` is not assigned; so... the compiler doesn't have many reliable options for you

Comment: @MarcGravell: Theoretically, the compiler could assign o in both cases, this is what I expected. As I stated in the question I do not see the point why I am allowed to specify variables in such a scenario when Iam not allowed to use them. Is there a scenario similar to mine where at least one if the variables are usable? Or is this a corner case I just discovered for which no special handling is implemented?

Comment: _"Theoretically, the compiler could assign o in both cases,"_ - no it can't since it would contradict the specification as far as I can see (see the latter part of my answer).

Comment: The feature could have been implemented that way, yes, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-switch-statement) (emphasis mine):

> A switch statement executes the statement list in the **first switch section whose case pattern matches** a match expression and whose case guard, if present, evaluates to true

So I would argue that this is quite expected actually. You have two paths leading to the `Console.WriteLine` and either one or another is matched (not both). In pseudocode it can look something like:

```
string s;
object o;

if(obj is string)
{
   s = (string) obj;
   goto doSomething;
}


if(obj is object)
{
   o = (object) obj;
   goto doSomething;
}

doSomething:
// your Console.WriteLine here
// Console.WriteLine(s); Local variable 's' might not be initialized before accessing
// Console.WriteLine(o); Local variable 'o' might not be initialized before accessing
```

So if the first one is matched the second one will not be processed (since arguably there is no reason to and specification says so) leading to `o` not being initialized and if second one is matched means that the first one was not, so `s` is not initialized.

And from the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1383-the-switch-statement):

> A `switch` statement is executed as follows:
>
> - ...
> - Control is transferred according to the value of the converted switch expression:
>
>   - **The lexically first pattern** in the set of `case` labels in the same `switch` statement that matches the value of the switch expression, and for which the guard expression is either absent or evaluates to true, causes control to be transferred to the statement list following the matched `case` label.
> - ...

As for "why the compiler does even allow me to specify variables in that scenario?" - because spec does not forbid it as far as I can see:

> Each `switch_section` consists of one or more `switch_labels` followed by a `statement_list` (§13.3.2). Each `switch_label` containing case has an associated pattern ([§11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/patterns#11-patterns-and-pattern-matching)) against which the value of the switch expression is tested.

So all patterns including the [declaration one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/patterns#1122-declaration-pattern) are allowed no matter how many switch labels are present in the switch section.